# Unexpected session time out on windows for air and cakephp application

Tags: php, apache-flex, cakephp, air

I have created a Adobe air application which uses a cake php serve side. The communication is handled using CPAMF and rest communication. This application is built for both windows and mac platforms.

In windows platforms when application communicates using CPAMF, it uses same cookie for request and response. When application switches to REST communication it sends the same cookie for the request and response contains some other cookie. This happens same for when it switches from REST to CPAMF. This lead the application to make a session timeout.

But In mac OS X application it uses same cookie for both REST and CPAMF communication and it works well.

Can anyone help me to solve the issue with windows. I have used same code for both widows and mac. Also I have changed the secure level of the cakephp configuration to low. "Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this question was the two different user agent generated by Window. when it communicates remotely the user agent is sends is "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.1" and when it communicates using REST the user agent is "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.1" .